# Dryer vent installations

Tags: dryer, vent

I think I have a pretty basic question… I bought a new dryer. The old dryer used a flexible vent out to the wall but also had a rigid small 90 degree elbow connecting the flex vent to the actually dryer. Do I need to use the rigid 90 degree elbow? Or can I clamp the flex vent right to the dryer? Thanks!

Comment: You dont have to use the rigid 90 deg bend, but it might be the best way to vent if you have the back of the dryer close to wall.

Comment: A photo of the pipe etc would help.

Comment: It is indeed close to the wall. The only thing I’m not sure of is how to attach the rigid elbow to the dryer, because the metal clamp doesn’t really do anything. Can I just used duct tape?